# this opreator for nested functions

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my question is silly one,I searched on `google` but I could't find anything useful.
Here I have module with 2 functions inside it and here is the code

```
var sample = (function(){
    var _return = [];
    _return.bar = function(){
        alert("hello world");
    };
    _return.foo = function(){
        function test(){
           this.bar();
        };
    };
    return _return;
})();
sample.foo();
```

And my questions:
How can I access to the bar function inside test function? I tried `this.this.bar()` or `parent.this.bar()` but none of them worked.
And how can I access it with this operator?

Comment: You really should use `var _return = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually (unless one has used `bind` to change the context of a function), the `this` context is bound to the object *on* which the function is being called, i.e., if you call `foo.bar()`, then inside `bar`, `this === foo`. In your case, since you are returning `_return`, you want to access the function `bar` which is defined on the same object, i.e. `this.bar`. However, since you will call `test` directly, `this` will be bound to the `window` object.

There are three main ways of working around this issue:

#### Save the context while you can

```
_return.foo = function(){
    var self = this;
    function test(){
       self.bar();
    };
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jcovmspr/

#### Use `bind`

The other approach is using `bind` (ES5):

```
_return.foo = function(){
    function test_(){
       this.bar();
    };

    var test = test_.bind(this);
};
```

#### Use arrow syntax

The third approach is using [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for defining `test` but this is ES6 only and you will need a [transpiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) to support more common browsers:

```
_return.foo = function(){
    var test = () => {
       this.bar();
    };
};
```

Comment: Oh my god How can I missed that solution yes your answer is perfectly logical

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure like below,

*Note: I prefer using 'that' or 'me' rather than 'self' because self is a special keyword in JS.*

```
_return.foo = function() {
    var that = this;

    function test(){
       that.bar();
    }
};
```

or you can use `bind`:

```
_return.foo = function() {
    var test = (function () {
       this.bar();
    }).bind(this);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Can you explain about your second solution I can't get it??

Comment: @Daniel.V `bind` allows you to return a *copy* of a function but with it's `this` keyword always pointing to the provided object as the first argument to `bind`. However `bind` is more powerful than this and allows to perform partial function application.

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to `_return` instead of `this`:

```
var sample = (function(){
    var _return = {
        bar: function(){
            alert("hello world");
        },
        foo: function(){
            return function test(){
                _return.bar();
            };
        }
    };
    return _return;
})();
sample.foo()();
```

(Also, I've used a proper object literal instead of creating properties on an array)

Comment: Perhaps he wanted an array however... there's no way to tell ;)

Comment: @Bergi I prefer to use array instead of object because I don't want to use _return in my module and actually I think the array approach is more structural

Comment: @Daniel.V: But that's not the difference between objects and arrays. You should only use arrays if you intend to fill it with items, use its `.length` etc.